# Python dictionary is ordered alphabetically - how do I order it chronologically?

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I'm following a tutorial (uploaded oct. 2020) about web scraping and storing the data in a dictionary. Everything works fine except the data in my dictionary starts with the newest entry and ends with the first one.

Should: {title,........, budget}

Is: {budget,........, title}

What could be the resaon for this to happen?

Part of the code:

```
def get_content_value(row_data):
  if row_data.find("li"):
    return [li.get_text(" ", strip = True).replace("\xa0", " ") for li in row_data.find_all("li")]
  else:
    return row_data.get_text(" ", strip = True).replace("\xa0", " ")

movie_info = {}

for index, row in enumerate(info_rows):
  if index == 0:
    movie_info['title'] = row.find("th").get_text(" ", strip = True)
  elif index == 1:
    continue
  else:
    content_key = row.find("th").get_text(" ", strip = True)
    content_value = get_content_value(row.find("td"))
    movie_info[content_key] = content_value
    
movie_info
```

index == 0 is the title

index == 1 is a picture i don't want to have

EDIT:
It's not reversed, it's in alphabetical order! Why? And how can i change it to chronological order?

Comment: you may want to use an OrderedDict object: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries are inherently not sorted/ordered.  This is unlike lists and tuples that are ordered.  To get around this issue, the `collections` library has [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

You can use something like this:

```py
# Import the OrderedDict object from `collections`
from collections import OrderedDict

def get_content_value(row_data):
  if row_data.find("li"):
    return [li.get_text(" ", strip = True).replace("\xa0", " ") for li in row_data.find_all("li")]
  else:
    return row_data.get_text(" ", strip = True).replace("\xa0", " ")

# Instead of using a regular dictionary ("{}"), we set `movie_info` to be an OrderedDict
movie_info = OrderedDict()

for index, row in enumerate(info_rows):
  if index == 0:
    movie_info['title'] = row.find("th").get_text(" ", strip = True)
  elif index == 1:
    continue
  else:
    content_key = row.find("th").get_text(" ", strip = True)
    content_value = get_content_value(row.find("td"))
    movie_info[content_key] = content_value
    
movie_info
```

Comment: I don't want to have it ordered by alphabet. You said dictionarys are normaly not ordered, but why is mine then? Correct me if I got you wrong

Comment: @Skywalker Alphabetical ordering is just how Python chooses to display dictionaries since they have no other order.  Using OrderedDict, as I did in the example, will preserve the chronological order in which you add elements.

Comment: @Skywalker did this resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, but you can do it like below.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three':3}
res = OrderedDict(reversed(list(dictionary.items())))
```